Resetting an objects counter in anylogic
Is there a way to reset the .count() of a source or a sink or any other object for that matter?
At the end of a day I'd like to record, how many agents passed through an element using the .count() function.

There is not (for good reason).
But you can always create your own counters and reset them any time you like:

drag in a variable myCounter of type int, initial value 0
in your Sink, add to the counter in the code box: myCounter++
reset anytime by simply by calling myCounter=0

